# Notepad++ add a new line if the lines contain a specific string

Tags: string, notepad++

Hi I'm trying to get something done using the research tool in notepad++ but i'm having a hard time.

basically I have a text file with hundreds of line that looks like this block repeating:

```
NAME SURNAME VVTX
06 XX XX XX XX (number)
ADDRESS
```

I want to add a new line everytime a line contains the "VVTX" part you can see above.

thing is, using the replace tool will add that line after "NAME SURNAME" which I don't want.

basically I want to add a new line at the beginning of any sentence that contains "VVTX"

I've tried searching for a way to swap words at the beginning so I could replace it after but it didn't work everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit according to comment**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*\R.*VVTX`
- Replace with: `\n$0`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  .*        : 0 or more any character but newline
  \R        : : any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
  .*        : 0 or more any character but newline
  VVTX      : literally VVTX
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n          : linefeed (you may use \r\n depending on your needs)
$0          : The whole match
```

**example:**

```
ante previous
previous
NAME SURNAME VVTX
06 XX XX XX XX (number)
ADDRESS
```

**Result for given example:**

```
ante previous

previous
NAME SURNAME VVTX
06 XX XX XX XX (number)
ADDRESS
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is working is there a simple way I can do the same thing but add the newline to the line right above the one where it matched? (merci toto)

Comment: @RaphaelHMoongaming: Is that what you want?

Comment: @RaphaelHMoongaming: De rien ;) You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: done I marked it on accepted but I got one last question and I'd feel bad to make another post for it. what should I change if I want to add to the end of line instead of beginning?

Comment: @RaphaelHMoongaming: put the linefeed after: `$0\n`